Is it possible to Hide the Errors and Warnings icons in Visual Studio 2022
I don't want to see the below icons when the Code Editor is Open.    I find it somewhat distracting.

I am fine with seeing these icons only when I open the Errors List Window.

If it's not possible to Hide the Icons can I turn them off from updating until I am ready?  Stack Overflow is asking me to write more text but I am not certain what else to write.
Thank you

I don't understand T.S.  The Bar that displays the Zoom is perpetually present when I open a file in the Code Editor.  I can only control the opening of the Error List Window.  I am running the latest version of VS.  I'll make it a little more clear in the question.

If you don't need to see these icons, you can uncheck the option Show file health indicator to hide Errors and Warnings icons(“No issues found”.) in VS 2022.
Tools->Options->Text Editor->General->Display


Thank you very much Dou.  This made my day!
